# drawing smooth and continuous curve

Tags: functions

I have been asked to draw a curve that is "smooth and continuous"
which passes through (5,0) and the domain is [-1,5) and range is (-infinity, 6]
No function is given just these conditions

How exactly would this graph look?

Comment: Are you sure it does not pass through $(0,5)$ since $(5,0)$ has an $x$-coordinate outside of the domain which seems to be a contradiction ...?

Comment: what do you mean? the domain is [-1,5)? The question states that the curve passes through (5,0)

Comment: Wouldn't it just be a straight line that does not have a y-intercept that passes through (5,0)? Or is it not a straight line since it says "Smooth and continuous

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that it passes through $(0,5)$ one solution could be
$$
f(x)=\frac{30}{x-5}+11
$$
Here is a link to Wolfram Alpha plotting that function:
[Wolfram Alpha plot of f(x)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28x%29=30/%28x-5%29%2b11%20for%20x%20from%20-1%20to%205)